# Passing value outside form

Tags: forms, grails, view, controller, gsp

I need to get the value from outside the form. My gsp looks like this

```
<g:textField name="email" value="${someInstance?.email}"/> 
<input type="button" id="checkEmail" class="button" value="Validate" onclick="checkEmail()"/>
<span id="responseDiv"></span>

<g:form action="save"> 
someCode
<g:submitButton disabled="true" style="color:#999999;" class="save" name="save" action="save" id="saveButton" value="${message(code: 'default.button.save.label', default: 'Submit')}"/>
</g:form>
```

First, to check if an email is in use, click button (id="checkEmail") and onclick goes to js code checkEmail() which has remoteFunction that updates responseDiv. After that, user  enters information to the form, and user clicks submitButton. When that submit button is clicked, I would like my gsp to send email value along with other information to the controller. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, put the input inside the form.
If that isn't an option for some reason, use the callback to update a hidden field inside the form with something like `$("#hiddenEmail").val(emailAddress);`

PS. I like how you gave a span an id of responseDiv :)

Comment: I was not sure of syntax to set set hidden field from DOM value. Can you let me know? Thanks.

Comment: What about putting the input inside the form element?

Comment: I cannot. For remoteFunction that I am using to work correctly, email field has to be outside of the form.